# How can I use ObjectTypeConverter to manage null values?

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

I have this converter to convert a Boolean.class field from the entity to a VARCHAR(1) in Oracle DB:

```
@ObjectTypeConverter(name = "SNtoBoolConverter",
    dataType = java.lang.String.class,
    objectType = java.lang.Boolean.class,
    conversionValues = {
        @ConversionValue(dataValue = "S", objectValue = "true"),
        @ConversionValue(dataValue = "N", objectValue = "false"),
    }
```

)
Is there a way to convert null values to a character?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you'll need to use a [custom converter](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/jpa/extensions/a_converter.htm). Something like:

```
  @Converter(name="SNtoBoolConverter",
       converterClass=org.myorg.converters.SNtoBoolConverter.class)
  Boolean yourProperty;


public class SNtoBoolConverter implements org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.converters.Converter {

  public Object convertDataValueToObjectValue(Object dataValue, Session session) {
    if ("S".equals(dataValue))
      return Boolean.TRUE;
    if ("N".equals(dataValue))
      return Boolean.FALSE;

    return null;
  }

  public Object convertObjectValueToDataValue(Object value, Session session) {
    if (null == value)
      return null;
    if (value == Boolean.TRUE){
      return "S"
    } else {
      return "N"
    }
  }
  public void initialize(DatabaseMapping mapping, Session session){}
  public boolean isMutable() {return false;}
}
```